# Possible mucus come out of eye when blow nose?

Tags: mucus-phlegm, sinus, nasal-congestion, nose-blowing, sinus-headache

I am super congested and I blew my nose a bit ago, and I felt that the sinus pressure was so severe that s mucus/phlegm excreted from the orifice of my eye somehow. **is this possible?** are the sinus cavities connected in such a way that mucus can come out the eye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 sinuses : frontalis, ethmoid, maxillary, and sphenoid sinus. Frontal sinus, it excrete mucus into the  meatus medius via a small opening called hiatus semilunaris anterior . Anterior and middle sinus of ethmoid also excrete mucus to meatus medius. The sphenoid sinus drainage to sphenoid recess. The two sinus drainage to meatus medius, but below the meatus medius there is another meatus called meatus inferior, it receive a drainage from ductus nasolacrimal ( it connect nasal cavity with eye) so if you cry the tears will be excreted to the nose. In your case i think the problem has nothing to do with the sinus, because there is no sinus drainage to inferior meatus. You may have a condition called nasolacrimal reflux, where the content in nose go up to the eyes (yes it is possible that you blow your nose too hard and causing the mucus exit via your eyes) . The content of the nose is not only mucus, it may mixed up with normal flora such as bacteria staphilococcus and or streptococcus. These bacteria may infect your eyes causing conjunctivitis. For you further reading http://www.jacionline.org/article/S0091-6749(05)03383-X/abstract